# Schengen Visa for a financially dependent Indian Citizen

Tags: visas, schengen, paris, singapore

I'm Indian passport holder working in Singapore for last 5 years. This August I'm planning to visit France & Rome for a 9 days tour with my wife. I will be applying for the Schengen Visa at France Embassy. Wife is not working she is in dependent pass in Singapore for last 2 years. While filling the form, I'm not sure what need to provide in question 33. Do I need to mention cost will be covered by herself or do I need to mention cost will be covered by sponsor & provide my information in the form? She doesn't have any bank account.

Please let me know what the exact procedure is.

Comment: What is question 33?

Comment: There is a lot of expertise on Schengen and Indian nationals here http://www.immigrationboards.com/other-countries/

Comment: See also http://eeas.europa.eu/delegations/india/more_info/faq/schengen_visa_en.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are comprehensive information portals directly by the EU.
Below is the information for India.

http://eeas.europa.eu/delegations/india/more_info/faq/schengen_visa_en.htm